# Redshift - Create Table based on Nested Common Table Expressions

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, create-table

What is the syntax to create a new table based on results returned from "nested" common table expressions (example below)?

**Example**:

```
   WITH allCustomers as (SELECT Customerid FROM Customer_tbl),
    customer_purchasing as (SELECT Customerid, 
                                   Item, 
                                   Price 
                            FROM allCustomers 
                            JOIN purchases_tbl 
                              ON allCustomers.Customerid = purchases_tbl.Customerid
                               ) 
SELECT * FROM customer_purchasing
```

**Question**: How can I create a new table based on the `customer_purchasing` 
CTE in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer while writing my question: A table can be created based on nested CTE's by adding the following syntax to the example query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE testtable1 as (
   WITH allCustomers as (SELECT Customerid FROM Customer_tbl),
    customer_purchasing as (SELECT Customerid, 
                                   Item, 
                                   Price 
                            FROM allCustomers 
                            JOIN purchases_tbl 
                              ON allCustomers.Customerid = purchases_tbl.Customerid)
SELECT * FROM customer_purchasing)
```